# disable (or grey out) all line items except what is checked

Tags: related-list, checkbox

Is there a way to disable or grey out all the line items in a related list view except the one checked? Currently Im using console view and simply displaying related record lists, I did not know if this is a capability without code.

Comment: does "checked" mean:  a) the user checked the item on the related list to select it or b) it is based on some value already saved in the record?  Are you looking to make the related list act like a set of radio buttons?

Comment: @cropredy checked means a line item on a related list was selected. If this is true, all other unchecked items should be greyed out. 

this is to prevent the user from selecting multiple line items at one time and accidentally updating multiple at one time.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without code. You would need someone to create you a Lightning Web Component, which behaves like a related list and that can do what you need.

Comment: Got it, I assumed a lightning web component could be a solution. LWCs are not something I am exceptionally knowledgeable on at this time, however.